# Visual Studio игнорирует библиотеки Unity

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio

У меня установлена Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 и для него я скачал инструменты для создания игр на Unity.

[image]

Но Visual Studio по прежнему не понимает библиотеки Unity.

[image]

**Как это исправить?**

Comment: Если под "Debu..." подразумевается `Debug`, то убедитесь, что у Вас подключено пространство имен `UnityEngine`

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский я не первый раз пишу скрипт. Конечно подключено. А по поводу Debug я просто хотел показать что отсутствуют даже самые простые функции.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский самое странное что он не показывает ошибку типа - Нет функции Debug, он просто не показывает эту функцию.

Comment: на некоторых компах в подобных случаях мне помогает перенос скрипта в решение с именем проекта -> в VS Файл -- Переместить <скрипт> в -- (выбрать решение с именем проекта)

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Где функция переместить? http://prntscr.com/ogb8zx

Comment: У меня предпоследним пунктом. И еще мне кажется странным заголовок VS - имя файла, а не Unity-проекта. Что-то не так с решением. Попробуйте удалить .sln, пусть Unity создаст его заново.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский проблема решена, читайте ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось просто надо было в настройках сделать Visual Studio основным компилятором.
Всё равно спасибо всем за внимание!